# Импорт модели django в файл python

Tags: python, django

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо использовать модель в файле main.py в папке telegram

Импортирую следующим способом:

```
from index.models import users
```

Получаю ошибку: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index'

Нашёл способ:

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("PYTHONPATH", "/usr/bin/python3")
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'PaymentForParking.settings')
django.setup()
```

Но теперь получаю ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PaymentForParking'. В manage.py и wsgi.py указано так же